# Why is the Twitter Bootstrap "fixed" layout NOT fixed?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

The Twitter Bootstrap site reads as follows:

> The default and simple 940px-wide, centered layout for just about any
>   website or page provided by a single `<div class="container">`.

Quote from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

That's exactly what I have in my HTML but when I inspect the element, I see this CSS apply to it:

```
.container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

By the way, if I override that CSS rule by adding...

```
div.container{
  width:940px;
}
```

Then the elements inside the div.container are wider than the div.container itself and look out of place.

So, why is the Twitter Bootstrap "fixed" layout NOT fixed? and how can I make it fixed?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: Sorry not yet. It's just in my development machine. I'll try to deploy it soon.

Comment: +1 to Jrod, i'm using the bootstrap fixed on several projects and do not experience this issue.

Comment: try posting your application.html.erb or similar to gist or pastebin.

Comment: Here is a cleaned version of application.html.erb http://pastebin.com/Dw2zzWZw

Comment: @leonel The cleaned version isn't of much use.  I was hoping to be able to inspect the project myself and view the css to see if there is an issue with overrides or just anything strange going on there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

In newer version of bootstrap, since 2.1.0 (I think) you can modify the responsive grid sizes in `variables.less` : [source on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.0/less/variables.less#L255)

So if you are compiling your CSS from Less, you can modify those variables. Otherwise, the solution below is still valid.

---

This is because you included the responsive layout. Check the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

If you look at this file [github responsive-1200px-min.less (2.0.4)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.4/less/responsive-1200px-min.less#L7) or [github responsive-1200px-min.less (2.1.0)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.4/less/responsive-1200px-min.less#L7)

You can see that

```less
@gridColumnWidth: 70px; // First parameter
@gridGutterWidth: 30px; // Second parameter
```

Which gives `70*12 + 30*(12-1) = 1170px` (12 being the `@gridColumns`).

So if you want the static, non-responsive, 940px wide grid, you have to remove the `bootstrap-reponsive.css` file from your includes.

As for the RoR equivalent of that, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have an up to date version of Twitter Bootstrap ?
My bootstrap.css says (line 197):

```
.container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 940px;
}
```

As you mention you are using twitter-bootstrap-rails the `vendor/toolkit/twitter/bootstrap/variables.less` states:

```
// Default 940px grid
// -------------------------
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         60px;
@gridGutterWidth:         20px;
@gridRowWidth:            (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@gridColumns - 1));
```

Thats the standard files right from the https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

You might be using some other version of it?

Comment: I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap-Rails and the `width:1170px;` line is reported in line 6674.

Comment: @leonel Then you are using a different version altogether and cannot rely on the documentation provided by the original bootstrap.  Refer to the documentation of your modified version.

Answer (score 0):

I think your miss understanding the term fixed for bootstrap. When `Bootstrap` mentions fixed they mean it doesn't re-size the width of the content based on the size of the browser, but Fluid will.

So if you change the container, you should also change the default width of the `row` class. ie: `.row { width: 940px; }`

you might have to do so with other classes as well. Bootstrap also provides a customization page [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variables)

Hope that helps,