# how to use bootstrap fixed width layout for 1170px width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Bootstrap Template which is Non-responsive. So the width of the Non-responsive design in Bootstrap is 940px. But the issue here is, I am requested to use the layout width for 1170px only. So I would like to know if there is any provision in Bootstrap for making Non-responsive layouts with 1170px width?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the older versions of Bootstrap did use 1170px, but it was changed to 940px ([Why is the Twitter Bootstrap "fixed" layout NOT fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904911/why-is-the-twitter-bootstrap-fixed-layout-not-fixed)). If you want to use the latest (2.3.1) the best thing to do would be to override .container in your CSS...

```
.container {
    width:1170px;
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/60156

Comment: Does it adjust the .span1... .span12 classes widths to fit inside container?

Comment: Yes, it would still adjust those as usual

Comment: Here is a Bootstrap 3 fixed width solution: http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/fixed-width

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the grid column width and the grid gutter width in the page of [Customize Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html). You need to increase the width of:

- @gridColumnWidth
- @gridGutterWidth

For example, if you put a `@gridGutterWidth` of 30px and `@gridColumnWidth` of 70px you will achieve that total width, without breaking the bootstrap grid.

EDIT: Also, if you are using LESS o SASS modify that two variables to accomplish that.